Eigen::Vector3f Elementwise compare and set individual to zero
I've 3 vectors that are used to store coordinates, velocity and acceleration in cartesian coordinate system along x, y and z axes.
I'm checking if either of these values is close to 0 (Zero) and if it is close to 0 I manually make them zero.
Is their an efficient (faster) way to achieve this?
Hardware Acceleration: AVX2
Code
Eigen::Vector3f coordinates;
Eigen::Vector3f velocity;   
Eigen::Vector3f acceleration;   
//Some operations on coordinates, velocity and acceleration
if( (coordinates(0) < 0.0001f) && (coordinates(0) > -0.0001f))
{
    coordinates(0) = 0.0f;
}
if ((coordinates(1) < 0.0001f) && (coordinates(1) > -0.0001f))
{
    coordinates(1) = 0.0f;
}
if ((coordinates(2) < 0.0001f) && (coordinates(2) > -0.0001f))
{
    coordinates(2) = 0.0f;
}
if ((velocity(0) < 0.0001f) && (velocity(0) > -0.0001f))
{
    velocity(0) = 0.0f;
}
if ((velocity(1) < 0.0001f) && (velocity(1) > -0.0001f))
{
    velocity(1) = 0.0f;
}
if ((velocity(2) < 0.0001f) && (velocity(2) > -0.0001f))
{
    velocity(2) = 0.0f;
}
if ((acceleration(0) < 0.0001f) && (acceleration(0) > -0.0001f))
{
    acceleration(0) = 0.0f;
}
if ((acceleration(1) < 0.0001f) && (acceleration(1) > -0.0001f))
{
    acceleration(1) = 0.0f;
}
if ((acceleration(2) < 0.0001f) && (acceleration(2) > -0.0001f))
{
    acceleration(2) = 0.0f;
}


A side note: it might not be faster, but if you implement the logic in a function accepting a Eigen::Vector3f by reference, it would make your code a lot more readable and maintainable.

@wohlstad All these objects are private data members inside a class. I'm not passing them as parameter to any methods.

You can still implement the logic in a single method as described above, instead of duplicating it for coordinates, velocity, and acceleration.

This question is similar to: Rounding numbers below a certain threshold to zero in Eigen. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@wohlstad Will this be the fastest way? I'd avoided methods/functions as I'm working on real-time low latency application. I'm already overshooting my execution time and I need to optimize my code.

Using inline methods will probably be at least as fast as your original code, but maybe not faster (this is why my original comment was written as a side note, as an advice from a software-engineering point of view).

Is their an efficient (faster) way to achieve this? - do you have performance test written? If not, then how do you prove there is any kind of improvement?

Your code can be reduced a lot without detailed knowledge of Eigen:

Write a function to process any Vector3f
Write a loop instead of hard coded iterating from 1 till 3
Use fabs for the absolute value


void normalize_zero(Eigen::Vector3f& v) {
      for (size_t i=1;i<4;++i) {
           if( (std::fabs(v(i)) < 0.0001f) v(i) = 0.0f;
      }
}

I expect Vector3f to be compatible with range based for loops, but I am not sure. If yes you should use one here.
The above and yours and other variants that conditionally assign 0f to the vectors elements can be expected to have comparable performance. Of course you need to measure if you care about the last percent, but only after you tweaked your compiler flags to optimize the code.

Will this be the fastest way? I'd avoided methods/functions as I'm working on real-time low latency application. I'm already overshooting my execution time and I need to optimize my code.

@DarkSorrow nothing in my code adds unecessary overhead. It does what it is supposed to do. YOu can only check a condition for all elements of a vector by checking a condition for all elements of the vector. Thats what your code does already. Chances are high you are trying to optimize on the wrong end instead of careful profiling and measuring to find the actual hotspots

Compiler explorer shows that it compiles away to a tight loop.
